# How to add transition to accordion open and close

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I am using headless ui and tailwind css. Currently the transition is just fading in and out when I open and close the accordion. I would like to make it slide in and out like the accordion here https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/accordion/

Here is my code. There was a lot of code so I just added the part that opens and closes

```
 <Transition
    enter="transition duration-100 ease-out"
    enterFrom="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
    enterTo="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
    leave="transition duration-75 ease-out"
    leaveFrom="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
    leaveTo="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
>
    <Disclosure.Panel as="dd" className="mt-2 pr-12">
        <p className="text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">{faq.answer}</p>
    </Disclosure.Panel>
</Transition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Tailwind` instead of `headless <Transition/>`. You can find the working example over  [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3kzggs?file=Accordion.tsx). The component looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  items: { title: string; description: string }[];
};

export default function Accordion({ items }: Props) {
const [openIndex, setOpenIndex] = React.useState(0);
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {items.map((item, i) => (
    <div key={item.title}>
      <div
        onClick={() => setOpenIndex(i)}
        className="cursor-pointer bg-red-100 border border-b border-black px-2"
      >
        {item.title}
      </div>
      <div
        className={`transition-all overflow-hidden duration-500 bg-green-100 px-2 ${
          openIndex === i ? 'max-h-screen' : 'max-h-0'
        }`}
      >
        {item.description}
      </div>
    </div>
   ))}
  </React.Fragment>
 );
}
```

`items` prop will be an array of objects with `title` and `description`. You can customize it based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faChevronDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Transition } from '@headlessui/react'

interface AccordianProps {
  items: { id: number | string, title: React.ReactNode; content: React.ReactNode }[],
  defaultValue?: number;
}
export default function Accordian(props: AccordianProps) {
  const { items = [], defaultValue } = props

  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue)

  return (
    <div className="bg-white border rounded-md">
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        const visible = value === index

        return (
          <div key={item.id} className="border-b last:border-b-0">
            <div
              className="px-4 py-2 flex items-center justify-between cursor-default"
              onClick={() => {
                setValue(visible ? undefined : index)
              }}
            >
              {item.title} <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} className={`w-4 h-4 transition-transform duration-300${visible ? ' rotate-180' : ''}`} />
            </div>
            <AccordianPanel
              visible={visible}
              defaultVisible={defaultValue === value}
            >
              {item.content}
            </AccordianPanel>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

interface AccordianPanelProps {
  visible: boolean;
  defaultVisible: boolean
}
function AccordianPanel({ visible, children, defaultVisible }: React.PropsWithChildren<AccordianPanelProps>) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  function setHeight() {
    ref.current!.style.height = ref.current!.scrollHeight + 'px'
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * 当默认要展示某一个 panel 的时候，第一次收起动画不能正确实行，使用下列代码修复
     */
    if (defaultVisible) {
      setHeight()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Transition
      // appear
      show={visible}
      ref={ref}
      className="px-4 overflow-hidden will-change-[height]"
      enter="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
      enterFrom="h-0"
      beforeEnter={setHeight}
      leave="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
      beforeLeave={() => {
        ref.current!.style.height = '0px'
      }}
    >
      <div className="py-2">
        {children}
      </div>
    </Transition>
  )
}
```